# How to use .arr sdk in my react-native library project

Tags: android, react-native, aar

I wanted to create react-native wrapper around android sdk of zoom.us (they provide video conference feature through that), I have created a git repo using their sdk https://github.com/manjeets12/ZoomApiWrapper, but problem is that they only provide `.aar` sdk and it is giving me error project with path ":sdkName" could not be found in project ':react-native-zoom-api-wrapper'

I tried to use many solutions liking putting `.aar` files within libs folder and compiling from there or using `flatDir` options, as they don't provide any maven repo alternative, I am not sure how should I proceed in using this

Comment: Did you overcome this problem?

Comment: will try sometime when I am free

Answer (score 1):

So I've found a solution:

My aar-name is: 'my_name.aar'. You need to add this file to the libs folder in the root of your android folder (same level as your build.gradle).

Your build.gradle file has to contain this:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'my_name', ext:'aar')

}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Your android project should compile then. Next step is to integrate the library to react-native.

```
npm install --save your_project 

react-native link your_project
```

And finally add this to your android/app/build.gradle

```
repositories {
   flatDir {
       dirs "../../node_modules/your_project/android/libs"
   }
}
```

For a working project see this git: https://github.com/transistorsoft/react-native-background-geolocation/blob/master/docs/INSTALL-ANDROID-RNPM.md